# Performace gains of searching with FTS over it with LIKE on indexed colum(s)?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, indexing, full-text-search

Subquestioning "[full-text search sql server 2005"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627583/full-text-search-sql-server-2005/3824263#3824263)

Would the use of FTS (Full Text Search) be faster in comparison with searches using tsql LIKE on indexed column(s)?
Why?
And how much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes FTS will be faster for searches in the middle of the column, like will only be faster if what you searching is at the start of the column

```
where lastname like 'S%'
```

will be fast

```
where lastname like '%S%'
```

will be slow and the index won't be used because it has to traverse the whole column

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your application requirements, the first thing to keep in mind is that FTS is word based, while LIKE is matching character patterns. So, for example LIKE will find '%rate%' in 'overrated' while an FTS search on 'rate' will not.

Beyond that, [SQLMenace's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832541/performace-gains-of-searching-with-fts-over-it-with-like-on-indexed-colums/3832573#3832573) covers the topic nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I certainly prefer seeing links to any docs...

["CONTAINS (Transact-SQL). SQL Server 2008 R2 Books Online"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) has paragraph:

- **"Comparison of LIKE to Full-Text Search**

  *In contrast to full-text search, the LIKETransact-SQL predicate works on character patterns only.
  Also, you cannot use the LIKE predicate to query formatted binary data.

  Furthermore, a LIKE query against a large amount of unstructured text data is much slower than an equivalent full-text query against the same data.

  A LIKE query against millions of rows of text data can take minutes to return; whereas a full-text query can take only seconds or less against the same data, depending on the number of rows that are returned*"